# Restore Windows loader after deleting partition

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, bootloader, 16.04

I am just install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 8.1, but while installing i deleted Windows reserved partition. I installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode, but i not sure, that windows installed in UEFI. 
[Screen shot of gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNHHm.png)

I created Windows bootable usb (FAT32) with unetbootin + gparted and tried to restore loader: create a new NTFS partition (sda2) and use many variants of restoring: standard MS repair startup tool (doesn`t help), commands

```
bootsect.exe /nt60 all 
bootrec.exe /fixboot
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd
```

some operations with grub: update, adding items to menu, and others.
I am little confused. And now I have next situation: when I switch on the laptop error message by windows loader are displayed. And I can boot Ubuntu only by choosing it in boot list(f9).  What should I do?

upd: [boot info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16053469/)

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: You have MBR(msdos) partitioning, now. And Windows in a logical partition. Windows with MBR only boots in BIOS mode from a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag which now is on sda2 which has no boot files. And partition structure for Windows looks more like a BIOS boot, but you have an ESP - efi system partition with only /efi/ubuntu, not Windows. Probably best to convert NTFS partitions back to primary, and Linux partitions to logical. If new Ubuntu install probably best to delete them and use fixparts or testdisk to convert logical to primary.

Comment: `/dev/sda2` is an NTFS primary partition that's marked with an active/boot flag. It may be that the system is bootable this way. OTOH, you might be right that primary/logical status would need to be modified. It's hard to tell without knowing the history of partition table changes on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is peculiar. It looks like you installed Windows 8.1 yourself in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, then installed Ubuntu in EFI/UEFI mode. That's not a happy combination; it's almost always best to boot both OSes in the same mode (BIOS or EFI), not to mix modes. Broadly speaking, there are three ways to proceed:

- **Install a BIOS-mode Ubuntu boot loader** -- This is likely to be the easiest way to fix your problem. The [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool can probably do this, or you can install `grub-pc` and then do a `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`.
- **Convert to GPT and install an EFI-mode Windows boot loader** -- See [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170306032145/http://sdnalloh.com/converting-win7-from-mbr-to-gpt/) for the general procedure to do this. Note that when you're done with the Windows BIOS/MBR-to-EFI/GPT conversion, you may need to re-register GRUB with the firmware. Again, Boot Repair may be able to do the trick. If you go this route, I recommend you disable your CSM so as to avoid the extra complication in your boot path that's created by having it active. (This complication created your problem to begin with.)
- **Keep your mixed modes** -- Many EFIs enable you to switch between BIOS-mode and EFI-mode booting by using their built-in boot managers (typically accessed by hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key early in the boot process, but details vary from one system to another). Alternatively, you could install my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) in Ubuntu and edit its `refind.conf` file: Uncomment the `scanfor` line and ensure that `hdbios` is among the options. Then, when rEFInd comes up, you should be able to boot either Ubuntu or Windows. Either way you do it, this approach assumes that you've got a working Windows BIOS-mode boot loader. That may already be the case, but I can't be sure of that.

Getting any of these options to work is likely to require at least some trial-and-error experimentation because of system-to-system differences in how EFIs boot and because there may be unexpected quirks that might complicate your particular setup. Lots of things can go wrong when you reconfigure your boot loaders, so you may well end up posting back again with a follow-up question.

No matter which route you take, I recommend you download and prepare the USB flash drive or CD-R version of rEFInd. (You can get images for both from [the rEFInd downloads page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html).) You should be able to use rEFInd to boot into Ubuntu no matter what the partition table looks like, so having rEFInd on an external medium can serve as an emergency boot tool if something goes wrong as you make your changes.

For more on why you've got a problem, see [my page on the CSM.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) Note, however, that my page is written with a configuration in which Windows is in EFI mode and Ubuntu gets installed in BIOS mode in mind, since that's the more common error to make. Yours is the reverse of that. The basic principles are the same, though.